# IonQ signup process and access via Google Cloud

Tags: ionq

I'm trying to sign up in [ionq](https://ionq.com/), but it seems that one needs to habilitate at least the Google Cloud Platform. The documentation is not too clear and I have -10 of experience for cloud platform.

Does anyone know if, to access via google, one needs to pay? Or is it possible to get a free account similar as in the IBM quantum experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The announcement (https://ionq.com/news/june-17-2021-ionq-quantum-computers-now-available-on-google-cloud/) makes it quite clear:

> IonQ’s systems will be the first third-party quantum computers **purchasable** via the Google Cloud Marketplace

> Developers, researchers, and enterprises alike will be able to access IonQ’s platform with just a few clicks; **billing and provisioning** will be handled via their existing Google Cloud accounts.

> “We’re thrilled to make our hardware available for **purchase** on the Google Cloud Marketplace, and we can’t wait to see the different workloads that developers start running,”

So to answer, no you won't be able to access these chips for free, except if someone else is paying for you (like a company or a research laboratory).